# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS seems to be impossible

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, http-redirect, nginx-config

I am posting the question because the previous attempts have proved to be futile.

I have a rails server using nginx, and I am trying to redirect all http traffic to https.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
upstream backend {
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin1.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin2.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin3.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin4.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin5.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin6.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin7.sock;
  server unix:PROJECT_PATH/tmp/thin8.sock;
}  

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 default_server ssl;

  server_name app_name;
  ssl_certificate path_to_certificate_file.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key path_to_certificatefile.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

  root PATH_TO_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  access_log path_to_project/log/access.log;
  error_log path_to_project/log/error.log;
  client_max_body_size 10m;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  location /ping {
    echo "pong"
    return 200;
  }

  # Cache static content
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|swf|wav)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }  

  # Status, local only (accessed via ssh+wget)
  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  # double slash removal
  set $test_uri $host$request_uri;
  if ($test_uri != $host$uri$is_args$args)  {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  }

  location / {
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;   
    }
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {    
    proxy_redirect off;  
    # Inform we are on SSL
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    # force timeouts if one of backend is died
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503;

    # Set headers
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    

    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

The current configuration causes:

> 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

You may notice the /ping location. That's because I have the servers behind a GCE balancer that performs a health check, and this is THE ONLY one I do not want to redirect. Everything else should be redirected to HTTPS.

Previous attempts:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name app_name;

  location /ping  {
    echo "pong";
    return 200;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}
```

With the https server part like the current config (with listen 80 default_server commented). This causes a too many redirections error.

I tried to simply redirect ALL traffic to https, including the health check. GCE expects a 200 response and instead it gets a 301, thus marking the machine as unhealthy and rendering the application useless.

I also tried the `ssl on;` on the https server config, same result (400)

I also tried to toggle the config.force_ssl = true in the rails project to no avail. Every other solution I try fails too.

Did anyone stumble on this also?

Comment: I also tried to create an https health check to go directly to the https part. The check doesn't work and puts my machine as unhealthy. Not to mention an https check can only be performed on a https backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was not the Nginx config, but the certificates. 
Putting a valid certificate led me to create an https backend and health check. Everything is working fine now.